# Radius of Convergence for $\frac{\sin(z)}{e^z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

We're asked to determine the Radius of Convergence for $f(z) = \frac{sin(z)}{e^z}$  centered at $z_0 = 1 + 7i$.

I'm not sure how to even start with this. I know that for $sin(z)$ and $e^z$ individually, R = $\infty$. Does this mean R is the same for the fraction?

I understand that the Radius of Convergence is the distance to the closest singularity. But Neither $sin(z)$ nor $e^z$ have any singularities. And since $e^z$ is never zero, then the fraction as a whole  doesn't have singularities either (?).

I also know that we have formulas to find R when our function is in the form $f(z) = a_k(z-z_0)$ but again, I can't figure out how to manipulate the function to look like that or if I even should be doing that.

Comment: What is the radius of convergence of the series for an entire function at any point?

Comment: is it not $\infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The radius of convergence for a quotient is at least the smaller of the input radii of convergence **unless the denominator hits zero at a smaller radius**.  The denominator hitting zero creates a singularity of its own which could control the radius of convergence instead of any singularities in either term.

So, given that each term gives an infinite radius of convergence, you then ask if there exists any $z$ at a smaller radius where the denominator $e^z$ is zero.  If such a $z$ exists you have a finite radius of convergence determined by that value of $z$.  If not you retain an infinite radius of convergence inherited from the separate terms

Comment: So since $e^z$ is never zero, that means the Radius of Conversion is $\infty$. My question is now though, does $z_0$ have any effect on this?

Comment: Not if there are no singularities.